# Using Jade in Play 2.0 Java : Custom agent class not found

Tags: java, playframework, classnotfoundexception, agents-jade

I'm currently trying to create agents with JADE platform in a Play 2.0 Java application. I use the basic java play template for this. My index method in the HomeController class goes like this :

```
public Result index() {
        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.instance();
            Properties p = new ExtendedProperties();
            p.setProperty("gui", "true");
            ProfileImpl pc = new ProfileImpl(p);
            ContainerController container = rt.createMainContainer(pc);
            AgentController agentController1=container.createNewAgent("Agent1","controllers.BaseAgent",new Object[]{""});
            agentController1.start();

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }
```

The container's GUI appears when I go on localhost which is fine. However I get the following error in the console:

**jade.core.IMTPException: Class controllers.BaseAgent for agent ( agent-identifier :name Agent1@10.32.6.48:1099/JADE ) not found - Caused by:  controllers.BaseAgent**

My BaseAgent class goes like this (and is indeed in the controllers package) :

```
package controllers;

import jade.core.Agent;

public class BaseAgent extends Agent {
    @Override
    protected void setup(){
        System.out.println("I am the BaseAgent");
    }
}
```

I thought the problem might be coming from the fact the container isn't initialized in a main method, but the application being a Play project there is no main method. It may also be related to a classpath problem, when I try to add an agent from the GUI I only get one option :

[Classpath contains one classes that extends jade.core.Agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVFQI.png)

Thank you very much from your help ! I'm having a lot of trouble trying to find what the problem is.

Comment: Did i undestand you correct? You build web application and try to run agent within it, dont you?

Comment: Yes indeed ! I need to run agents in this application.

Comment: does your built .war file contain the agent class in classes or libs?

Comment: Hmm I didn't package my Play app as a war file, should I ? I'm a beginner in both Play and Jade so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: what tools do you use? IDE ussualy builds artefacts which are run. Do you use maven?

Comment: I don't use maven, only Typesafe Activator to build/run the project and IntelliJ to code it.